# How workflow authentication works in SharePoint 2013

Tags: workflow-manager

How workflow Authentication Happens in SharePoint 2013.
We have installed workflow manager 1.0 for SharePoint 2013 Workflow.
I just want to know how authentication works for user for workflow.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil, can you be more specific about Workflow Authentication? Do you mean Workflow 2010 or 2013 engine? Do you want to authenticate with an external service from a workflow?